# Error in split == TRUE : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r

This is the line of code that is generating the said error. The variable 'y' contains values '0' or '1'. There are about a dozen different variables in the dataframe. I'm using R version 3.4.1.

```
set.seed(201)
library(caTools)
spl = sample.split(bank$y, 0.7)
training <- subset(bank, split == TRUE)
```

Comment: Also, welcome to SO :)

Comment: I have used the subset function a couple of times before and `=` never works. `=` results in training set having the same data frame as 'bank'. `==` always worked though, except for this data set.

Thanks, glad to be here. Still figuring out the place :)

Comment: Sorry, I should think before I type, subset needs a comparison operator. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have your data, but it looks like you're just calling an object by the wrong name.

```
training <- subset(bank, spl == TRUE)
```

Should work.

Personally, I prefer the following, simply because it's more logical to my brain, but it's doing the same thing:

```
training <- bank[ spl == TRUE, ]
```

You can go further, but it might make less sense, depending on how your brain works:

```
training <- bank[ spl, ]
```

To explain: You create a vector called `spl` with the following:

```
spl = sample.split(bank$y, 0.7)
```

That gives you a logical vector, with the intention of subsetting your data frame to the rows corresponding to the `TRUE` values in `spl`. In order to do that, you use `subset` or similar. `subset` asks for an input (bank) and a vector to use as the subsetting operator. The vector is a logical vector, `TRUE` for "use this" and `FALSE` for "don't use this". Your subset parameter is `spl`, which will look something like `TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,....`, so you can pass it directly to `subset`.

Note that in the case of a logical vector, passing the vector with "== TRUE" will actually return the identical vector:

```
spl <- c(T,T,T,F,F)

> spl
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> spl == TRUE
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

That's why you can use `spl` or `spl==TRUE` interchangeably.

Comment: >calling an object by the wrong name.


Could you help me understand that a bit better. Like where I might be wrong. I'm very new to coding and stats so still figuring out the basics.

Comment: `training <- df[ spl == TRUE, ]` This is the error I get when I try that solution. 

`Error in df[spl == TRUE, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: Your `df` is actually `bank`, I've just used `df` to be more general.

Comment: @SpaceMonk There's a function in R by the name of `df`, relating to the F distribution. If you use `df` in your code without assigning a data frame to it, R assumes you're talking about the function, which isn't subsettable. :)

Comment: I've changed all references to `bank` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oops, that's an embarrassing mistake :)

I retried your solution and it worked. Thanks so much for the help!