# Still getting Error in split == FALSE : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, split

This topic has already been discussed in this [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772184/error-in-split-true-comparison-1-is-possible-only-for-atomic-and-list-typ/45772328) but I still get the same error after following the suggestions when I try to split my data `data_csv` with the following code:

```
x <- model.matrix(RET ~ ., data_csv)[,-1]
y <- data_csv$RET

#install.packages("caTools")
library(caTools)
set.seed(101) 

split <- sample.split(data_csv$RET, SplitRatio =0.8)
train.set <- subset(data_csv, split == TRUE)
test.set  <- subset(data_csv, split == FALSE)

y.train <- train.set$RET
y.test <- test.set&RET

X.train <- as.matrix(subset(train.set,select=-c(RET)))
X.test <- as.matrix(subset(test.set,select=-c(RET)))
```

Comment: It is impossible to know without reproducible data. We do not know what kind of an object `RET` is. We do not know if there are missing values in your data. What does `table(split)` show?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.